# Sending mail from the command line, in an automated way

Tags: ubuntu, email, script, automation

I want to be able to send a text file through an SMTP server of my ISP (port 25) to an email address on the internet, like my Office email address, or my GMail address. I have a basic Ubuntu 9.04 server setup on my DSL connection.

How can I use, say, Postfix, to send the .LOG file, on a bash script ? What would be the packages to install on that server, given it was never used to send email in the past ?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/) seems like a nice tool for that. From what I get from the documentation it would be just a call like this:

```
sendEmail -f <myadress> -t <destination> -u <subject> -m <message> -a <pathtofile> -s <serveradress> -xu <username> -xp <password>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the [ssmtp](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/132006) package. Since it's a sendmail emulator, it is highly compatible with all kinds of stuff that might want to send email.