# Execute command/script after file transfer

Tags: email, script, openssh, transfer

I've configured a server (Ubuntu) with OpenSSH for file transfer via sFTP. The requirement is that after a file transfer, a mail is sent confirming the file was received by the system. How would I do this without having to poll the directory every x time for new/changed files?

Answer (score 0):

Refer **[Checking script results and Send a mail](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#results)** and **[Automate file transfers (or synchronization) to FTP server or SFTP server](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation)**

**Example:** sending a email using command prompt

```
winscp.com /script=example.txt
if errorlevel 1 goto error

echo Success
sendmail.exe -t < success_mail.txt
goto end

:error
echo Error!
sendmail.exe -t < error_mail.txt

:end
```

Refer one more answer related to sending an email, **[Sending mail from the command line, in an automated way](https://superuser.com/a/39647/103323)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this is on the client side, I'd like to do this on the server side without any additional commands issued by the client.